# ReferenceError: kendo is not defined

Tags: angular, kendo-grid

I tried to create a sample application for loading kendo-grid wrapped in a angular2 component. When I try to run the application I am getting the exception in the chrome browser like below

```
angular2.dev.js:24821 EXCEPTION: Error in :0:0BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:24821
angular2.dev.js:24821 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: kendo is not definedBrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:24821
angular2.dev.js:24821 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:BrowserDomAdapter.logError @ angular2.dev.js:24821
angular2.dev.js:24821 ReferenceError: kendo is not defined
    at Kendogrid.setUpGridOptions (Kendogrid.ts:23)
    at new Kendogrid (Kendogrid.ts:19)
    at AppView._View_Kendogrid_Host0.createInternal (Kendogrid_Host.template.js:15)
    at AppView.create (angular2.dev.js:22641)
    at ComponentFactory.create (angular2.dev.js:7668)
    at angular2.dev.js:8215
    at angular2.dev.js:8192
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:349)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (angular2.dev.js:2185)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:348)
```

I am not getting any other exception details and not able to proceed further on this issue.

I tried replicating the same issue in the [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview)

If I try to use the reference which is on HTTP, then I get the following error

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:25 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:26 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:27 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.default.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:28 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/js/jszip.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
run.plnkr.co/:1 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object](…)
```

the Last error message shows the following stack trace

```
angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]
        at InvalidProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4383:27)
        at new InvalidProviderError (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4645:20)
        at eval (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5590:23)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at _normalizeProviders (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5573:19)
        at eval (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5584:17)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at _normalizeProviders (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5573:19)
        at eval (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:5584:17)
        at Array.forEach (native)
    Error loading https://run.plnkr.co/6WhTDJtCImd7LHoc/src/main.ts
```

Can any one share some light on this, and let me know what is the issue/mistake done by me?

Comment: If you load this Plunker with `http` instead of `https` then ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE doesn't happen anymore but there is a jQuery error now. And the import path in `Kendogrid.ts` should be `./Grid` instead of `./grid`. Maybe you can continue from there to make the "unexpected identifier" exception reproducible.

Comment: @Günter, I did the change to Http from the Https in the plunker (But still i use Http only in my local. because of the secured connection error Earlier I changed to Https). Also I did the change for .Grid in the import statement. I am getting different set of errors, any ideas?                  New Error Message:  angular2-polyfills.js:349 Error: Error: Invalid provider - only instances of Provider and Type are allowed, got: [object Object]
        at InvalidProviderError.BaseException [as constructor] (https://npmcdn.com/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:4383:27)

Comment: Can you post the link to the plunker in the most recent state. I suggested http instead of https only to make it work in Plunker which has some restriction you don't have otherwise.

Comment: @Günter, I have updated the plunker with the latest code now as is from my local, https://plnkr.co/edit/GpVY7KsFT0aExAz3G7ka?p=preview , can you please take a look and help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. the following code is used to generate kendogrid wrapped in the angular2 component.

```
  private setUpGridOptions() {
        console.log("in setUpGridOptions of ExtractorQueueGrid");
        var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: this.configSetttings.DATACACHEAPI_EXTRACTORQUEUESERVICE_URL
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log("Status: " + e.status + "; Error message: " + e.errorThrown);
            },
            pageSize: this.constants.KENDO_GRID_DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
            schema: {
                model: {
                    name: "ExtractorQueueGrid",
                    fields: {
                        queueId: { },
                        name: {},
                        addedDate: { type: "Date" }

                    }
                }
            }
        });
        this.options = {
            dataSource: dataSource,
            columns: [
                { field: "queueId", title: "QUEUEID", width: "8px" },
                { field: "name", title: "NAME", width: "20px" },
                { field: "addedDate", title: "ADDEDDATE", format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", width: "10px" }
            ],
            pageable: true,
            groupable: true,
            sortable: true,
            selectable: true
           // click: "onChange",
        }
    }
```